# Generics in java just checking to make sure this is correct

Tags: java, generics, bounded-types

I'm struggling with these (similar) problems on the bounded quantification of generics in Java:

1. Write the header for a generic class named MyType. The class should have one type parameter. The type parameter’s upper bound should be the String class.
2. Write the header for a generic class named MyType. The class should have one type parameter. The type parameter’s lower bound should be the Integer class.

   ```
   public class myType<T extends String>{}
   ```

   and

   ```
   public class myType<T extends Integer>{}
   ```

is this correct im really having a hard time grasping the concept of generics in java

Comment: Hang on, there are headers in Java? Like [headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_file)?

Comment: `String` and `Integer` are a final classes and cannot be extended.

Comment: #2 asks for *lower* bound, not upper bound.  (Whether or not Integer can be extended is irrelevant).

Comment: Would I use super for the lower bound??

Comment: How do I call it to make the lower bound and upper bound I keep getting back that I use extends for the upper bounds??

Comment: I'm not sure which is upper and which is lower, but one of these should be `<T extends _>` and the other should be `<T super _>`

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen No, binary is all that's needed to use a Java library.  Header there just meant 'first line' pretty much.

Answer (score 3):

You don't use `extends` to define both the upper bound and the lower bound.

According to [Wikipedia's article on Generics in Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)...

> To specify the upper bound of a type wildcard, the extends keyword is used...

So to define the upper bound, use `extends`:

```
public class myType<T extends String>{}
```

Again, according to [Wikipedia's article on Generics in Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java)...

> To specify the lower bounding class of a type wildcard, the super keyword is used.

---

### Addendum

I think whoever originally put this question together needs to sort a few things out.

- Java does not have header files. Look up Header Files on Wikipedia, and [it immediately states that Java does not use them](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_file#Alternatives):

  > Some newer languages (such as Java) dispense with header files...
- You cannot use a lower bound when defining a class - I believe it can only be done with a wildcard, which is not used when defining a class. The code `public class MyClass<T super Integer> {}` will give a syntax error: `> expected`

So all together, the question reeks of nonsense.

Comment: Thats what I had read to but I wasnt sure this would be considered a wild card since I dont have the ? in the code

Comment: Ya, to be honest, I think whoever wrote this question might have been taking crazy pills - I don't think a class definition can have a lower bounding on the generic, but I'm not sure.

Comment: lol right I hate the damn book my college picked Ive had to purchase to other books just to help me solve this damn books problems haha

Comment: lol by "whoever wrote this question" I don't mean you, @ChadBenjamin - I assume this problem was given to you by someone else.

Comment: I hope it works out. If these are the kinds of questions you're facing, it might be a lose-lose scenario... but either way, welcome to StackOverflow, and I encourage you to check [the SO policy on expletives](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites) - some people make a big deal out of it ;)

Comment: Thank you im here to learn haha ;p and my apologizes on that I was just clarifying how dead I am haha 3 semesters away for a bs in computer science........... Im thinking of a new major haha.